# How can I reinforce my outdoor fan mounted to 2x8 so it doesn't wobble?

Tags: fans, mount, board

[image]
There is a fan installed on my outdoor patio to a 2x8. This is a high wind area and I noticed the other day that it was wobbling back and forth constantly. I removed the cover and found that the fan is mounted directly to this board with 2 small screws. It has me very nervous that this thing will eventually drop and hurt someone.
What do you think would be the best way to reinforce this mount to stop the wobble? Should I redrill the 2 holes all the way through the board, and get some bolts, washers, nuts, and locktite? It is there something else you would recommend?
Thanks so much!

Comment: i might craft a backup safety net with a strip of pipehanger screwed across the metal bracket like a seatbelt. Most of the wobble though should be on purpose; the ball and socket of the fan motor assembly itself. Those are meant to swivel to find the natural level on sloped ceilings.

Comment: It's the base that's attached directly to the wood that has become loose and is rocking back and forth

Comment: Wobble is usually caused by poorly balanced fan blades. Ceiling fans are designed to accommodate some wobble.

Answer (score 3):

There's a concerning lack of a junction box here, for the first thing.

Install a fan rated junction box connected to the framing.

Comment: I guess the reason for no junction box is so the cover part touches the wood and doesn't leave a gap?

Comment: It is precisely the fact that you have electrical connections in contact with wood (and related inadequate fan support) that is concerning.  AFAIK an electrical code violation at least in USA/Canada. Ask your fan manufacturer if they recommend installing this way, or look at the instructions covering your fan's installation.

Comment: I found some 1/2" deep junction boxes! I'm going to take a look at them and see if they will solve my problems

Answer (score 1):

Check first what is wobbling, is it a loose base or a loose fan to base mount.

Loose base can be fix with larger screws or bolts. Might need to add screws/bolts to the outside sections if just the two screws in the centre sections, to spread out the force.

Fan to base would need tightening of joint/s.

Comment: It's the base attached directly to the wood that is wobbling

Comment: With just two screws on the centre line, might be the problem.  Using a screw on each of the outside sections at each end should help in high wind conditions.

Comment: I'm going to look tomorrow to see if that's possible. I may have to drill some holes through the base to be able to. That would definitely help with the rocking problem

Answer (score 0):

I grabbed a 1/2" saf-t-pan and installed that to the wood with 5 wood screws then mounted the fan. There's a small gap at the top now but the fan is rock solid

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a picture of or link to a 1/2" saf-t-pan for those who don't know what that is.

Comment: Here is a link to the one I got. It came with the wood screws as well. Westinghouse Lighting 0103611 Saf-T-Pan, 1/2-Inch Deep https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B0046ZTGMI/ref=cm_sw_r_apan_i_9PQAK6B67TT4NW32X8ZZ?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1